# Why does a download-enabled <a> allow file data in the href?

Tags: html, download

Having a downloadable file in HTML5 is fairly straightforward in code.

```
<a href="/files/whateverFile.txt" download="fileNameForUser.txt">
```

This takes the file at the location of the href, and kicks it over to the OS to download that file with the filename in the download="fileName" parameter.

What I don't get is when you do this

```
<a href="data:application/txt;charset=utf-8,theseAreTheFileContents" download="fileName.txt">
```

This will ask the user to download fileName.txt which has "theseAreTheFileContents" as the text inside. The data is in the page itself, and the browser doesn't look to any other URL for the data required.

Why are the file contents in the href? Href is about telling the browser the location of a certain resource. Why not have more fields in downloadable anchors?  Such as

```
<a href="null" datatype="application/txt" charset="utf-8" data="theseAreFileContents" download="fileName.txt">
```

Isn't that more clear? Href shouldn't mean more than one particular thing.

Answer (score 0):

`data:` scheme URLs are a [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) (one that predates the `download` attribute).

They weren't created for use with anchor elements (and are more commonly seen to embed small images inside CSS files).

Anchor elements weren't designed to link to embedded data, they just support it because the `data:` scheme exists.